# Pascal exam procedure, dont understand

Tags: pascal, freepascal, turbo-pascal

[This is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgsl7.png)

Can someone please help me, I really do not understand how on earth did they get x*y in this procedure ... Question asks what does procedure do ?

```
    PROGRAM iz52(output);
    VAR pom: integer;
    FUNCTION calc(x,y: integer): integer;
    BEGIN
    IF (y=1) THEN
    calc:= x
    ELSE
    calc:= calc(x, y-1) + x
    END;
    A) x+y 
    B) x*y
    C) x^y
```

Comment: Please.... do not link an image of code (especially when their hard for folks like me with bad prescription glasses). Put the code directly in your question. To your question, it's determining if you understand recursive calls. And, yes, the correct answer is `x * y`. Walk through  it step by step. Take an example, like `x=2` and `y=3` and pretend you're the computer and get a pencil and paper and work through it.

Comment: Sorry for putting image, I did not know... Can u please tell me what those calc:=calc(x,y-1) + x;  do ....  i dont understand calc(x,y-1) part, only that i do not understand ?

Comment: Look up `recursion`

Comment: Even if you read it, you can tell: `calc(x, y)` is computed by first computing  `calc(x, y-1)` (if `y` > 1) then adding `x`. If `y` has the value of  1, then you just get `x` (makes sense: `x` is `x * 1` right?). The `calc(x, y-1)` is calculating the result of `calc` where first argument is `x` and second argument is `y-1`. It's a "recursive" call.

Comment: `calc(x,y-1)` is a function call. `+ x` is well, addition. `calc :=` assigns to the function return value. Did you go to class at all?

Comment: Rather than have us tell you the answer (they are looking for B) why not try to work it out for yourself?

Comment: Yes I did try to work it for myself couple of times, but did not understand the recursion procedure... now I finally think i understand it. For example: y=3 ..... calc(x,3)+x= calc(x,2)+x+x= calc(x,1)+x+x+x = 3x = x*y  did I got this correct ?

Comment: Well done. Don't give up too soon. You can do this, and it's better to do it yourself, you will learn more.

Comment: Plug in values of x and y and look at the results. It might make it more obvious of you created a table with three columns, 'x', 'y', and 'calc', and you pick values of y greater than zero, it should be clear that calc does x*y for values of y greater than zero.